# Strip single ended tags from string (img, hr, etc)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
function stripSingleEndedTag($content, $allowed = array()){
(array)$allowed;
$singletags = array('<meta>','<img>','<input>','<hr>','<br>','<link>','<isindex>','<base>','<meta>','<nextid>','<bork>');

$stripthese = arrayfilterout ($singletags, $allowed);
$stripthese = str_replace(array('<','>'),'',$stripthese);

$pattern = '/<('. implode('|', $stripthese) .')[^>]+\>/i'; 

$content = preg_replace($pattern, "", $content);
return $content;
}
```

What I've got here will strip out a single ended tag like `<bork />` but only if there is some character after 'bork' and before '>'.  `<bork >` and `<bork/>` are stripped, but not `<bork>`

BTW, cant use `strip_tags()`.

Comment: What original task are you solving in such a weird way?

Comment: It looks like this is the culprit: [^>]+ on line $pattern = ... It matches one or more non > characters. If you change it to [^>]*, then it will probably start working.

Comment: @doliver , That seems to work, thanks.  I had a feeling it was a problem of 'one or more' vs 'zero or more'. Thats the difference, correct?  Does this also solve the problem you mention on OregonTrail's answer?

Comment: Yes, that is the difference. No, it does not solve the problem he gave on the original example. The problem that was that he used .* which means zero or more of any character. By default, regex is greedy which means it will go for the largest possible expression that it can match. That means if it can match >>>>>>> instead of > it will. This is a problem in the case of tags because if you have a tag wrapping the entire document then it will match the whole document instead of one tag. [^>] forces it to match only until it comes to a > character. So in summary [^>]* is correct, not .*

Answer (score 2):

**You can use:**

```
$pattern = '/\<('. implode('|', $stripthese) .')[^>]*\>/i';
```

***Original Answer:***

Do you want to get rid of `<bork />` and `<bork/>`, but not `<bork>` and `<bork >`?

It looks like what you want is:

```
$pattern = '/<('. implode('|', $stripthese) .').*\\\>/i';
```

*Update:* fix for greedy match:

```
$pattern = '/<('. implode('|', $stripthese) .').*?\\\>/i';
$pattern = '/<('. implode('|', $stripthese) .')[^>]*\\\>/i';
```

Comment: .* will match more than it should when regex is greedy. So, you could get something like <tag1><tag2></tag2></tag1> and it will match something like <(tag1><tag2></tag2></tag1)>

Comment: I want to get rid of all 4 examples that you gave above: `<bork />  <bork/> <bork> <bork >`